# How can I do a search textbox?

Tags: html, css, forms, search

I wish to do a search box just like this:

[image: Wallbase.cc's search box]

Analyzing the code, I saw that it uses a image as background and repeats it horizontally.

But I have no idea on how will I transform this as a input field.

Please help me?

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying to transform your input field?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "transform this as a input field".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in css, let's say you have the html code:

```
<input type="text" name="searchBar" />
```

and than you can add the style in the css stylesheet, like:

```
 input {
    background-image: url('photo.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }
```

or you can add an id to the html input tag and target it in css by it's id.
if you have more questions just ask and the stack community will be glad to help.

also i recommend to check this link -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp